# How do I get the text within HTML tags?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I want to get the text within a certain HTML tag. It looks like:

```
<div id="data123">data1: value1<br>data2: value2<br> data3: value</div>
```

My code looks like:

```
html_page = Nokogiri::HTML open 'my_url'
who_is_raw = html_page.css('div#data123')[0] #.text
```

I get either the text within the `<div>` tag without `<br>` tags or the whole `<div>` with all `<br>` inside. But, I want only the text within that `<div>` tag and `<br>` tags inside it.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with [`inner_html`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet.html#method-i-inner_html)

```
who_is_raw = html_page.css('div#data123')[0].inner_html
```